# How to get datepicker value on enter keypress?

Tags: php, jquery

If I press the enter key after giving the text box value like 03/20/2014 the result will appear. But if I give the value using date picker that doesn't work.

```
<input class="search-query" id="date" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){return true;}" type="text" name="date" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">

<script>
 $(function() {
  $( "#date" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the date when the user selects it, you can do something like this:

```
$ ("#datepicker").datepicker (
{
    onSelect: function () 
    {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    } 
});
```